# Update the items of a table from my application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, desktop-application

How can I update the items of a table from my application without using Entity Framework?

I have written a stored procedure to get values from invoice and presented in a `DataGridView`.

But I don't know how to update the database.

Kindly help

Comment: Two options: use ADO.NET to execute SQL `insert` or `update`, or write a stored proc and call that.

Comment: I'm using visual studio community 2015 I tried to add ADO.NET but It is not available in community I'm trying to update it so that I can Find it.

Comment: In winForms @Richard.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, I confident ADO.NET (assembly `system.data`) is available in all installs of .NET (whether VS is installed or not).

Comment: Yeah I have used it before but publish tool is not available while updating to get publish tool I thinks I have mistakenly uninstall the ADO.Net that's why I'm finding a solution to update without using entity model.

Comment: EF uses ADO.NET to talk to the database: if you don't have ADO.NET then an EF entity model won't be able to talk to the database. If straight ADO.NET is not working directly, but EF is working then there is something strange going on.